# how to change src of iframe dynamically in the flutter web?

Tags: html, flutter, iframe, webview, flutter-web

I am trying to set the new URL(i.e an HTML string) which I am parsing every time the src changes. but with this code, I am able to show only the first src and it is not changing and showing the same src of output every time.
class IframeView extends StatefulWidget {
String url;

```
frameView(this.url);

@override
_IframeViewState createState() => _IframeViewState(url);
}

class _IframeViewState extends State<IframeView> {
String url;
_IframeViewState(this.url);
final html.IFrameElement _iframeElement = html.IFrameElement();

 Widget _iframeWidget;


 @override
 void initState() {
 _iframeElement.height = '500';
_iframeElement.width = '500';
_iframeElement.srcdoc = widget.url;
_iframeElement.style.border = 'none';

// print("src printing");
// print(_iframeElement.srcdoc);
// print("widget url");
// print(widget.url);



ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('iframeElement', (int viewId) {
  return _iframeElement;
});

_iframeWidget = HtmlElementView(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  viewType: 'iframeElement',
);

super.initState();
}

@override
void didUpdateWidget(IframeView oldWidget) {
super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
print("from did update widget");
print(_iframeElement.srcdoc);
_iframeElement.srcdoc = widget.url;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
  child: _iframeWidget,
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
Widget buildVideoView(Key key) {
    String? videoFileUrl;
    String iFrameId = <some id defined in this stateful class>;

    if (<default url flag>) {
      videoFileUrl = <defaultVideoUrl>;
    } else {
            videoFileUrl = <new url>;
      IFrameElement element = document.getElementById(iFrameId) as IFrameElement;
      element.src = videoFileUrl;
    }

    html.IFrameElement _iframeElement;
    Widget _iframeWidget;
    _iframeElement = html.IFrameElement();
    _iframeElement.id = iFrameId; << this is important
    _iframeElement.height = '100%';
    _iframeElement.width = '100%';
    _iframeElement.allow = 'accelerometer; gyroscope;';
    _iframeElement.allowFullscreen = true;
    _iframeElement.src = videoFileUrl;
    _iframeElement.style.border = 'none';

    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
    _iframeWidget = HtmlElementView(
      key: key, << also important to prevent flicker/jitter/restart on rebuild
      viewType: 'iframeElement',
    );
    return _iframeWidget;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using _iframeElement.src = widget.url (not .srcdoc) and updating with a redraw function.

```
static redraw(String newLink, String newTitle) {
IFrameElement element = document.getElementById('contentz');
element.src = newLink;
```

}